# How to update a firebase document field based on a value from another document in other collection? Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a number in the usersnumber collection (counter document), and I want to take that number and put it in the users collection in the number field (as you can see in the photo). Is there any way I can get the data from usersnumber and update the users > collection > document > number?

[image]

[image]

I expect having the number 10 from the usersnumber collection in the collection users > document > number: 0

Comment: Do u want this to be a single time operation. Or u want the users collection to be updated everytime there is update in usersnumber collection?

Comment: I want it to be a single time operation

Answer (score 1):

> a transaction is a set of read and write operations on one or more
> documents.
>
> Using the Cloud Firestore client libraries, you can group multiple
> operations into a single transaction. Transactions are useful when you
> want to update a field's value based on its current value, or the
> value of some other field.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions

```
import { runTransaction } from "firebase/firestore";

try {
  await runTransaction(db, async (transaction) => {
    const sfDoc = await transaction.get(sfDocRef);
    if (!sfDoc.exists()) {
      throw "Document does not exist!";
    }

    const newPopulation = sfDoc.data().population + 1;
    transaction.update(sfDocRef, { population: newPopulation });
  });
  console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Transaction failed: ", e);
}
```